# Bluetooth doesn't turn on

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I can't turn on bluetooth. When i open bluetooth settings I get this showing me that bluetooth is turned off:

When I try to turn it on, the switch turns blue, but nothing happens. When I close settings and re-open it, it still shows me that bluetooth is turned off and the switch is turned back off.
[image]
I tried using rfkill to unblock it, but when I used `sudo rfkl list` it shows me that bluetooth is neither hard blocked nor soft blocked.

I also tried restarting the driver using

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

and rebooted, but it still didn't work.

It occasionally works when I restart my computer, but sometimes it doesn't even after restarting. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Not really an answer, as I'm using 18.04 where I can switch bluetooth off with a button that would be in the upper left of your screenshot and turn on again with a lengthy button in the lower 2 thirds reading something like "turn of flight mode". Rant, rant, rant: when I'm paranoid, I sometimes thinkt developers make joke of breaking downward compatibility.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 (with kernel 5.11.12). I have something that works for me everytime I want to use the bluetooth:

1. Turn the bluetooth on on that setting's screen you are showing (eventhough it still says that its off, just click on the 'on' toggle on the top right corner).
2. While its on, run the commands you just said:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sleep 1
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Then I can start to see all the available bluetooth devices and connect to them (I use a playstation 3 controller via bluetooth and haven't had a problem with the connection)

The downside is that everytime I turn the bluetooth off or restart the computer, I have to repeat the steps 1 and 2. I'm still looking for a more stable solution.

I also tried blueman but it didn't solve the issue.

I hope we can find a more permanent solution soon.

Comment: Hi, as of 04.07.2021, after today's Ubuntu firmware update, this problem was resolved in my machine! I hope this is the same for everyone.

Comment: facing the same issue in my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS x86_64 (kernel 5.15.0-56-generic), followed the steps above, but stilll not showing any bluetooth devices in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same with my bluetooth 5.0 dongle, which all of a sudden didn't work after a kernel update to kernel version 5.15 on Ubuntu 20.04.

For some reason Linux kernel 5.15 is now looking for rtl8761bu_fw.bin and rtl8761bu_config.bin.

1. Download the rtl8761b configuration and bluetooth driver files from GitHub if you don't already have them:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8761b_config
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek/rtk1395/bt/rtkbt/Firmware/BT/rtl8761b_fw
```

2. Move the files to the /lib/firmware/rtl_bt directory:

```
sudo mv rtl8761b_config /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_config.bin
sudo mv rtl8761b_fw /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin
```

3. Rename the rtl8761b driver to rtl8761bu:

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_config.bin /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
sudo cp /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
```

4. Reboot